# python socket send and recv issue

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sockets, websocket

Just new to python, I have a public IP with port and I have to send a query to it over tcp socket. In return it should return me a response "Yes" or "No" , like 1 = yes, 0 = no boolean value. Here is my simple code

```
import socket
hostIP = 'public_IP'
port = 443
message="mymsg"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((hostIP, port))
res = s.send(message.encode())
reply = s.recv(1024).decode()
print(reply)
```

The issue is I always get a connection reset,

```
python3 ss.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/abdul/ss.py", line 8, in <module>
data =  client.recv(1024)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

It seems to get killed on recv. Please help

Comment: This error means the client closed the connection. Which is normal and your server should probably use try/except to detect it.

Comment: @user253751, the server is 3rd party. I think it has to do with my code.

Comment: Is ss.py the server or the client?

Comment: @user253751, it is the client

Comment: Could the server be waiting for more message?

Comment: @user253751 This is the query and it is just one message. So no ! How can I debug this socket stuff ?

Comment: How does the server know that it has received the whole query?

Comment: Well at the end of the string, we append \r\nQUIT\r\n that tells the message has ended. The reset seems to happen only when I call the recv() function

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" means the server closed the connection. Maybe you should ask the people who made the server. Maybe Wireshark will help with your own troubleshooting